# Why when adding manual with Paint 4 pixels to image and then scanning the bitmap with GetPixel i'm getting many pixels?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an image that is clean from specific pixels. 
I edited the image in Paint and added manualy with one click on the green color and it added 4 pixels.

Now i'm scanning the image with GetPixel and indeed i'm getting a result of 4 pixels.

This is in form1:

```
cloudPoints = new List<Point>();
Bitmap bmpWithClouds = new Bitmap(@"D:\clean_image.gif");
ScanForClouds.cloudalert1(bmpWithClouds);
cloudPoints.AddRange(ScanForClouds.clouds);
```

This is how the clean_image look like:

[image]

Ok i think i know what is the problem but not why it happen.
While writing my question message here and uploading the images i saw that the second image is different then the first one.

When the first one look like high quality clear and sharp the second image which i edited the first one added more points and saved it with new name the second one looks like with low quality looks like the second image have many points in it.

This is the second image:

[image: Second image]

But i edited with paint the first image and just added more 3 points and saved it as gif file but in different name so why the quality is so low ? 
I checked both files the first one and the second properties both files are 512x512 8bit and gif type.

But second one looks strange with many many points in it.
No wonder when scanning the second image i'm getting so much points in it.

Comment: Is this for a class, I remember about a year ago someone asking a very similar question about drawing radar data on that exact same background image.

Comment: Maybe i asked it but not year ago so maybe it's not me. The radar is ready and working fine the class with the radar but the problem is the quality of the image/s why the quality changed from the first image it was sharp clear and the second looks so low quality. And i used Paint on both images.

Comment: If you re-save a .gif using MS Paint, heck yes it's going to look like crap. You should try using a better format and image editor.